# Is it possible to set a multi-line title to a Toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

please see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGmVa.png (the single "lorem" is a subtitle)

I am using the v7.21 appcompat library. I'd like to set a title to a Toolbar and if its too long then it should show as it does now (upper example in the image attached), only 1 line and it ends with ... if it doesnt fit. However I want the toolbar to expand (and then collapse respectively) onClick (possibly animated somehow) and show the full title (lower example)

Now I miss a few things here:

- I dont see any method which would tell me if the title fits or not. (getSupportActionBar().isTitleTruncated() returns false even if the title doesn't fit, but maybe this is not the method I need, its not even a method of the [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)'s class)
- I can't seem to set the Toolbar's height programatically (even if i could, animating it would be a pain even more because I am targeting >=api15)

Is it possible to execute what I want or should I find a different solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create custom toolbar 
here is the example

```
/**
 * Create the Action Bar and set the Custom View to it.
 * Set content insets absolute (0,0) to hide the bottom margin for Action Bar.
 *
 */
public void initializeAppToolbar()
{
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    actionbarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar,null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    actionbar.setCustomView(actionbarView, layoutParams);

    Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) actionbarView.getParent();
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.top_nav);

    toolbar_title   = (TextView)actionbarView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    // set click listener on toolbar_title.. and perform expand and collapse

    // need to check this condition for lollipop and greater version
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusBarDark));
    }
}
```

here is the custom_actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/top_nav"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Profile"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```